# How to reverse a string within an array?

Tags: java, recursion

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

class FileReverse{
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

      //charAt(int index): Returns the char value at the specified index.
      //substring(int beginindex, int endindex): Returns a new string that is a substring of the string. 
      //valueOf(char c): Returns the string representation of the char argument

      Scanner in = null;
      PrintWriter out = null;
      String line = null;
      String[] token = null;
      int i ,n ;

      // check number of command line arguments is at least 2
      if(args.length < 2){
         System.out.println("Usage: FileCopy <input file> <output file>");
         System.exit(1);
      }

      // open files
      in = new Scanner(new File(args[0]));
      out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(args[1]));

      // read lines from in, extract and print tokens from each line
      while( in.hasNextLine() ){
         // trim leading and trailing spaces, then add one trailing space so 
         // split works on blank lines
         line = in.nextLine().trim() + " "; 

         // split line around white space 
         token = line.split("\\s+"); 

         // reverses the input and prints it to the console.
         n = token.length;
         for(i=0; i<n; i++){
            stringReverse(token[i],(n-1));
            System.out.println(token);
         } 
      }

      // close files
      in.close();
      out.close();
   }

   public static String stringReverse(String s, int n){
      if(n == 0){
         return s.charAt(0) + "";
      }

      char let = s.charAt(n);
      return let + stringReverse(s,(n-1));
   }
}
```

We are given a file with this input

abc defg 
hi

jkl mnop q
rstu v wxyz

and it must be returned as

cba
gfed
ih
lkj
ponm
q
utsr
v
zyxw

My code compiles but I keep getting an indexoutofboundsexception and I can't figure out to fix this. Help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What list throws the exception? Can you include the stacktrace please?

Comment: i think your output is wrong, where does the `g` in `gfed` come from?

Comment: Yes, the output seems either incorrect or different "waxy" becomes "zyxw" too

Comment: Reversing a string is the same whether it is in an array or not.

Comment: As Java strings are immutable, invoking `stringReverse(token[i],(n-1));` is pointless anyway. You need to do something with the returned value.

Answer (score 1):

You are splitting the `String` at each whitespace. in the following code

```
n = token.length;
for(i=0; i<n; i++){
    stringReverse(token[i],(n-1));
    System.out.println(token);
}
```

you check how many elements where seperated by whitespaces. But the mistake you are making is, that you are parsing `n-1` to the function `Stringreverse` (aside of the fact that you don´t store the return value). You are using the second argument as the `length` of the `String`, but what you are doing currently is, 
you are passing the amount of array elements that you got returned after splitting the initial `String` by whitespaces. You should call it as:

```
for(i=0; i<n; i++){
    String reversed = stringReverse(token[i],token[i].length()-1);
    System.out.println(reversed);
}
```

Comment: it seems like it is giving me the addresses:            [Ljava.lang.String;@232204a1
[Ljava.lang.String;@232204a1
[Ljava.lang.String;@4aa298b7
[Ljava.lang.String;@7d4991ad
[Ljava.lang.String;@7d4991ad
[Ljava.lang.String;@7d4991ad
[Ljava.lang.String;@28d93b30
[Ljava.lang.String;@28d93b30
[Ljava.lang.String;@1b6d3586

Comment: @MonserratPalabrica did you create a class and named it `String`?

Comment: oops sorry I did not do that! I have done that now and it prints out abc as cba but it prints defg as just fed and then I get an arrayindexoutofboundsexception                                                                                     cba
fed
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
 at FileReverse.main(FileReverse.java:41)

Comment: @MonserratPalabrica replace the for loop with the one i wrote at the end of the question and the exception should be gone.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
for(i=0; i<n; i++){
    stringReverse(token[i],(n-1));
    System.out.println(token);
 }
```

from

```
for(i=0; i<n; i++){
   token[i]= stringReverse(token[i],token[i].length()-1);
   System.out.println(token[i]);
}
```

You have to pass the each string size (not the taken array size) to the stringReverse method.

I am not sure why did you use following code inside the for loop

```
System.out.println(token);
```